# Can't connect to Raspberry Pi with external IP in local Network

Tags: networking, router, ssh, port-forwarding, raspberry-pi

I set up a port forwarding for my Raspberry Pi to be able to connect from the internet via ssh. When I try connecting to my Pi via internet of my mobile phone it works perfectly. As soon as I try connecting via local connection it does not work with the external ip. Just with the local ip of the Pi in my network. 
I have got a AVM FritzBox 4020 GM Router connected to my Speedport W723V Router which is used as a DSL modem.

Comment: This will only work if your router supports [NAT Reflection/NAT Loopback/NAT Hairpinning](http://www.nycnetworkers.com/real-world/nat-reflectionnat-loopbacknat-hairpinning/). Most consumer grade routers don't.

Comment: which router supports that feature?

Comment: I've no idea...

Comment: @DavidPostill That's the right answer. You should post it as an Answer.

Comment: @user6825883 I know Apple's AirPort line does. I would hope that any aftermarket open source firmware distro like OpenWrt would do this right; I can't imagine the open source router firmware community tolerating a bug like that for long.

Comment: You are in luck. The AVM FRITZ!Box does support loopback, according to http://opensimulator.org/wiki/NAT_Loopback_Routers, so you *should* be able to get it to work in your particular case.

Answer (score 1):

#### Cannot connect to an internal resource using a public IP from local network

This is only possible if your router supports [NAT Reflection/NAT Loopback/NAT Hairpinning](http://www.nycnetworkers.com/real-world/nat-reflectionnat-loopbacknat-hairpinning/).

Many consumer grade routers don't support this.

There is a list at [NAT Loopback Routers](http://opensimulator.org/wiki/NAT_Loopback_Routers) of routers that *do* have this functionality.

The AVM FRITZ!Box does support loopback (according to the above link), so you *should* be able to get it to work in your particular case.

---

#### Why is NAT Loopback needed?

> Many DSL routers/modems prevent loopback connections as a security feature.
>
> This means that a machine on your local network (e.g. behind your DSL router/modem) cannot connect to a forward facing IP address (such as 199.149.252.44) of a machine that it also on your local network.
>
> Connecting to the local IP address (such as 192.168.2.40) of that same machine works fine.

Source [NAT Loopback Routers](http://opensimulator.org/wiki/NAT_Loopback_Routers)

Comment: Actually, there are quite a few consumer grade routers that do support this, [this](http://opensimulator.org/wiki/NAT_Loopback_Routers) lists a few of them and among them is the AVM Fritz!Box.

Comment: I know that my FritzBox supports NAT Loopback but the router which is used as a modem does not support it in terms of security. Is that the reason why the Loopback is not working?

Comment: @user6825883 What is the Pi connected to? What device are you trying to connect from? - and where is that device connected?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be much easier to simply having two accounts in your ssh client(s) on mobile device(s)? One account for connection from outside of your local network and another one for the case when your inside of local network. Just use different IP in both accounts.

If you have some decent firewall/router such as [pFsense](https://pfsense.org/) for example and you owning some domain name then you can map your external IP to you domain/subdomain and on the LAN side override domain name by pointing it to the local IP address of Raspberry Pi. This way you need to setup in your SSH clients domain name only as a target IP to connect. When you outside of your LAN, your client will use public DNS to find your Pi, otherwise when you connected to your LAN, your firewall/router will override public DNS by substituting local IP of Pi for that particular domain